# Engine vs Engine Database

Tags: engines, analysis

Does anyone know of engine vs engine databases? Like stockfish vs leela vs komodo pgns for 1000s of games with a lot of time per move? I want data for how draw rate changes as engine rating goes up, and am willing to sift through the data.

I see there have been tournaments recently, but I'm having trouble getting the data. The more variant the data (multiple engines, multiple ratings, multiple dates) the more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to this site:

https://ccrl.chessdom.com/ccrl/4040/games.html

You should be able to download pgns of games by month, or games played by any specific engine of your choosing.

Also on the home page:

https://ccrl.chessdom.com/ccrl/4040/

You can search around and find stats of how certain engines score against each other.